# Parse.com: retrieve JSONArray and JSONObject from server

Tags: android, parse-platform, arrays, illegalstateexception, json

I've been working with Parse.com db in my android application, and I can't seem to get pass this error for the last few hours.

All I want is simply retrieve a JSONObject and JSONArray from Parse.com, but I keep getting 'illegalStateException', and I have no idea why. I've looked everywhere, and I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my creation of the JSONObejct: (Same goes for array, but i'll save you the trouble):

```
JSONObject x = new JSONObject();
    try {
        x.put("col_1" ,23.234);
        x.put("col_2" ,14.34);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("JSON_CREATION", e.getMessage());
    }
    newClient.put("fff", x); // This is a ParseObject ojbect, which I later save using 
                             // saveInBackground()  (and also tried with 'save()'
```

The above code works perfectely, and I also checked in Parse.Com that indeed a new object, with those specific values was saved.

Now all I need is to rerieve this data. This is what I do:

```
**JSONObject a = newClient.getJSONObject("fff");** // This line throws 'illegalStateException'
    try {
        double b = a.getDouble("col_1");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Would appriciate any help.

Comment: review the 'get objects' section of the parse docs. Review parse queries in the docs. Then look at your statement "getJSONObj...".. invoke a parse query for response of JSON objects instead of what u have

Comment: can you please specify a bit more? I already have the parseObject which the query is supposed to return. my problem is that I can't retrieve one of its fields which is a JSONObject
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.

It appears that the instance of ParseObject I was holding was not up-to-date (I thought I fetched it before).

The solution was to call x.fetch() / x.fetchInBackground() / x.fetchIfNeededInBackground() etc.
I didn't need to run a query, since, as I was saying - I was holding an instance of this object.

Hope that helps.